# How do I create a Rewrite Rule in IIS to temporarily conceal all PDF files?

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewriting, http-status-codes

I've got some PDF files sitting out on a web server, and for the time being I would like to hide them (i.e. have them return 404s). Can this be accomplished in the web.config file with a Rewrite Rule?

In Apache you can do this with something like this:

```
RewriteRule \.pdf$ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

How do I accomplish the same effect with IIS?

Comment: Are the files placed in a seperate folder ?

Comment: No they are not; they're in the root directory of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using the **HiddenSegments** in IIS. HiddenSegments would make URLs inaccessible to clients. Also, IIS  will return an `HTTP 404` error to the client and log the `404.8` HTTP substatus.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <hiddenSegments>
               <add segment="pathofpages" />
            </hiddenSegments>
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT 1:**
You can also use [RequestFiltering](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering) to Deny the PDF extension for the clients. `HttpStatus sub code 404.7`would be returned. All requests for PDF files will be denied.

From [IIS.net](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions)

> In the Request Filtering pane, click the File Name Extensions tab, and
>   then click Deny File Name Extension... in the Actions pane.

Comment: Is there any way to apply this to certain file extensions, and not just to whole folders?

Comment: you can specify the URL of each file as well, not just the folder.

Comment: Perfect, Request Filtering is exactly what I was looking for.